# What is the default width of a UIPickerView component?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Should be simple to find out right? Where in the Apple docs does it list any default values for various UI components?

I've tried calling the protocol's method:

```
CGFloat width = [self pickerView:pickerView widthForComponent:0];
```

...but no luck. How do i find out this default value?

Comment: Found out how:

CGFloat width = [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width;

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before but maybe...

viewForRow:forComponent:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/viewForRow:forComponent:

then get the width from the UIView returned