# Default value for height and width of components in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

What is the default value of the height and width of the components in UIPickerView? ie., what is the value that iOS uses as height and width for the below, if the application has not implemented these methods?

```
pickerView:widthForComponent:
pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
```

I tried the suggestion from the thread :
[What is the default width of a UIPickerView component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443306/what-is-the-default-width-of-a-uipickerview-component)
But that would give an array out of bound exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The width depends on the number of components in the picker. It is automatically calculated (as far as I can tell). The height seems to be around 44. Don't worry about getting it to be exactly what Apple's default is. I mean you're hard coding it anyway, so your app will be off by a few pixels if Apple decides to change it. I suggest just choose a height by trial and error, starting around 44 and see what "feels" best depending on the data you're displaying.

Comment: What if I want to customize the height and width for one component but leave the default values for the rest. I would want the default values to change when Apple changes them. In which case, hard coding might not help.

Comment: As soon as you override widthForComponent or heightForComponent, you're hardcoding. If you hardcode one, you have to hardcode the others. Afaik, the "default" values are not officially documented anywhere, so it's trial & error, or guess.

Comment: "if Apple decides to change it" on iOS, it won't affect your compiled code... at some point you're forced to update your Xcode and if you want to submit changes to your App... but then you can hardcode again!